# How to treat an instance variable as an instance of another type in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a simple inheritance heirarchy with `MyType2` inheriting from `MyType1`.

I have an instance of `MyType1`, `arg`, passed in as an argument to a method. If `arg` is an instance of `MyType2`, then I'd like to perform some logic, transforming the instance. My code looks something like the code below.

Having to create a new local variable `b` feels inelegant - is there a way of achieving the same behavior without the additional local variable?

```
public MyType1 MyMethod(MyType1 arg) 
{
    if(arg is MyType2)
    {
        MyType2 b = arg as MyType2;
        //use b (which modifies "arg" as "b" is a reference to it)...
    }

    return arg;
}
```

Comment: There is likely a better solution to what you are doing here, if you are willing to show what the different execution paths, you could probably get help refactoring the code so that you don't have to do this typechecking. Oftentimes what you are doing here could be considered a code smell.

Comment: I understand explicit type checking like this can be considered a smell - and I may refactor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the "is" and "as" is duplicating the test; *either* use `is` and then (once you know) just cast - *or* use `as` in the first place and test for `null`.

Re your issue; if you only want to do one thing - then cast:

```
if(arg is MyType2)
{
    ((MyType2)arg).SomeSpecialMethod();
}
```

Otherwise - perhaps a `virtual` method (on the base-type), or just refactor the logic out into another method, so you have:

```
if(arg is MyType2)
{
    StuffThatTakesType2((MyType2)arg);
}
```

But *persoanlly*, I'd just use the extra variable:

```
MyType2 whatever = arg as MyType2;
if(whatever != null) {
    whatever.Foo = 123;
    whatever.Bar();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No; you need to create a separate variable.

[Also, your code performs more casts than necessary; it would be a little bit faster like this:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182271.aspx)

```
MyType2 b = arg as MyType2;
if(b != null)
{
    //Use b 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say option 1 is to put all the modifying code (your comment line) as a function of MyType2, and then do `(arg as MyType2).Foo()` on it.

Option 2 is to implement MyMethod on both MyType1 and as an override in MyType2, and just call it without worrying. The MyType1 implementation may do nothing, which isn't the best design.

edit: technically not a violation of LSP since that only applies in the reverse of this situation (MyType2 shouldn't break behavior of MyType1).